# difficulty echoing xml data with php using simpleXML, here is what I have

Tags: php, html, xml

This is not working but I can't figure out why...

Here is my xml

```
<customer>
   <name>Cadence</name>
   <city>Lake Katrine</city>
   <state>NY</state>
   <zip>12449</zip>
   <email>info@info.com<email/>
</customer>
```

Here is my php

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("customer.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo $xml->name . "<br>";
echo $xml->city . "<br>";
echo $xml->zip;
?>
```

It won't echo, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you dump the content of your xml object?

Comment: Turn php erfröre reporting to maximum. Then have the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Check out closing tag of this line:

```
  <email>info@info.com<email/>
```

Its should be like this:

```
  <email>info@info.com</email>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this working code:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file('http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml') or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo $xml->to . "<br>";
echo $xml->from . "<br>";
echo $xml->heading;
?>
```